# Is VBA still the state of art for automating Office?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, ms-office

I am wondering if VBA is still the way to go if one wants to write macros or automate Office product "from within"? I do not have the possibility to craft a separate/external program which uses an API (like Visual Studio Tools for Office, DocumentFormat.OpenXML etc.) to manipulate Office documents.

I would prefer to use a .NET language like C#. Is that possible?

(I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941814/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-developing-msft-office-macros-in-a-non-v) question was asked 8 years ago. Though I have little hope, maybe something has changed since then...)

Comment: What's changed is Office itself. State of the art Office is now Office 365 which you can extend (partially) using web technologies: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins I doubt anything has changed (or will change) for desktop Office in that "from within" area.

Comment: What do you mean "from within"? Do you mean a built-in IDE that comes with the product (AFAIK VBA only)? Or do you mean code embedded in a document (VBA only)? Or do you mean a binary that adds functionality to an Office application (VBA addin, VSTO, or a COM addin using any Automation-supporting language), as opposed to writing an external program or script that manipulates Office objects (any Automation-supporting language, including .NET languages)?

Comment: Also, see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/18/roadmap-for-apps-for-office-vsto-and-vba/) (admittedly somewhat dated).

Comment: @ZevSpitz "From within" in the sense that I need only an installation of Office in order to edit code that is run by the application - no need for external code editors (VS) or compilers.